# Table column count in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am uploading csv file to mysql database.

Need to check manually check 
eg.number of row is match with database table column.

1.how to get table's column count in cakephp?
2.No table data ,i want only column count in table.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the solution provided in the most upvoted answer in the duplicate topic as a raw query.

Answer (score 1):

You can access protected objects value `_schema`

```
$columnCount = count($this->Site->_schema);
```

`Site` is model that You are interested in

Comment: Now , I tried like that

Comment: $columnCount = count($this->Ticket->_schema);
  echo $columnCount;

Comment: but return 0 in view

Comment: Now I found answer,  $columnCount = $this->Ticket->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = 'schema_name' 
    AND table_name = 'table_name'");
  debug($columnCount);  Thank you form your reply.